# How to create a loader Spinner in Angular 5

Tags: angular5

I am new in angular 5. I want to create a  mock json data in my service and i want to create a Spinner loader  when  i clicked the button .To display the spinner few   seconds,in Angular 5 .
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [ngx-spinner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-spinner) in your project. It's very easy to install and you have many options of spinner.

First Step: Install the lib

```
npm install ngx-spinner --save
```

Second step:
Import the lib in your module (app.module.ts)

```
// Import library module
import { NgxSpinnerModule } from 'ngx-spinner';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
    NgxSpinnerModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Third step: Add (or edit) the code below in your app.component.html

```
<ngx-spinner bdColor="rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8)" size="medium" color="#dd8f44" type="line-scale-pulse-out-rapid"></ngx-spinner>
```

Fourth step: Use in your component or service

```
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner'; <--

@Component({
  selector: 'app-client',
  templateUrl: './client.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./client.component.scss']
})
export class ClientComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private spinner: NgxSpinnerService <--
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.spinner.show(); <---
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.getClients();
      this.spinner.hide(); <---
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

I hope I helped you

Comment: we no need to use plugins Thank You

Comment: Hi, sorry for lateness. See this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qR-Cj1dGgkM Maybe help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Angular Material Progress Bar](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-bar/overview#indeterminate).